# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2) into shape (0) with groupby-splitted Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

The following function is a part of `socceraction` package.

```
import pandas as pd
from typing import List,Callable
def gamestates(actions : pd.DataFrame, nb_prev_actions: int =3) -> List[pd.DataFrame]:
    states = [actions]
    for i in range(1, nb_prev_actions):
        prev_actions = actions.copy().shift(i, fill_value=0)
        prev_actions.loc[: i - 1, :] = pd.concat([actions[:1]] * i, ignore_index=True)
        states.append(prev_actions)
    return states
```

I tried to apply it for subsequent groups of `df` Data Frame as follows.

```
df = {'half_id': {1: '1', 36: '1', 259: '1', 314: '1', 324: '1', 335: '1', 798: '1', 834: '1', 906: '1', 
                  1114: '1', 1170: '1', 1354: '1', 1494: '1', 1588: '2', 1688: '2', 2190: '2', 2227: '2', 
                  2435: '2', 2734: '2', 2838: '2'}, 
      'variable': {1: 1.0, 36: 1.0, 259: 1.0, 314: 1.0, 324: 1.0, 335: 1.0, 798: 1.0, 834: 1.0, 906: 0.0, 
                   1114: 1.0, 1170: 0.0, 1354: 0.0, 1494: 1.0, 1588: 1.0, 1688: 1.0, 2190: 0.0, 2227: 1.0, 
                   2435: 1.0, 2734: 1.0, 2838: 1.0}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df)

for _, half in df.groupby('half_id'):
     game_states = gamestates(half, 3)
```

However, this resulted in following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kuba/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-60-6df63fdacba0>", line 15, in <module>
    game_states = gamestates(half, 3)
  File "<ipython-input-60-6df63fdacba0>", line 7, in gamestates
    prev_actions.loc[: i - 1, :] = pd.concat([actions[:1]] * i, ignore_index=True)
  File "/home/kuba/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 670, in __setitem__
    self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
  File "/home/kuba/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 985, in _setitem_with_indexer
    setter(item, v)
  File "/home/kuba/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 961, in setter
    s._data = s._data.setitem(indexer=pi, value=v)
  File "/home/kuba/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 561, in setitem
    return self.apply("setitem", **kwargs)
  File "/home/kuba/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 442, in apply
    applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
  File "/home/kuba/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 914, in setitem
    values[indexer] = value
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2) into shape (0)
```

The issue doesn't persist while I'm calling a function not on a splitted, but original DataFrame:

```
gamestates(df, 3)
```

The error seems to be raised at `setitem` method, while assigning the output of `gamestates` function to `game_states` variable. But I'm scratching my head why and can't find a reason, possibly missing something obvious here. To be honest, the `Value Error` message about broadcasting arrays is unclear to me. So my question is: what is the cause of this error? How splitted with `groupby` Data Frame is different to original one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing inherently different about the split and the original DataFrame (apart from the first being a subset of the second, obviously):

```
frames = [f for _,f in df.groupby('half_id')]
type(frames[0]) == type(df) #  True (both are of the type pandas.core.frame.DataFrame)
```

The error occurs when calling `gamestates` with the second split DataFrame, i.e. `gamestates(frames[1], 3)`, because you are trying to assign a DataFrame of shape (2,2) to a DataFrame slice of shape (0,2) in the following line (when `i == 2`):

```
prev_actions.loc[: 1, :] = pd.concat([actions[:1]] * 2, ignore_index=True)
```

I'm not quite sure what the code is meant to do, but be aware that `.loc` provides access using labels, and since the lowest label in `frames[1]` is 1588, `prev_actions.loc[: 1, :]` will result in an empty slice.

The reason the error does not occur when using the original DataFrame `df`, is that this includes the label 1 which prevents an empty slice. To me it looks like the data structure is not correct for the given function.

Comment: Damn, the darkest place is under the candlestick! It was quite obvious, but somehow I couldn't figure out it myself... Thanks. And just for the sake of completness - the code is meant to create a list of shifted data frames with missing first rows filled by the first row of the original data frame. Switching to `iloc` solved the issue.